# Show each element of a struct in a template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am very new to elixir / phoenix. All Im trying to do is to render a template with a query result and display all records of the query in the view. For this I have added the following codes in my template:

```
<% Enum.each(@items, fn(item) -> %>                                                                                                                                                      
  <%= item.name %>                                                                                                                                                                        
<% end) %>
```

Here I am passing `@items` from my controller. This code gives me a blank page. I do not see any error either. However, if I change `<%= item.name %>` to `<%= IO.puts item.name %>` I see all the names displayed in my server console.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `map` because it returns value. And put `<%=` in the very beginning.

```
<%= Enum.map(@items, fn(item) -> %>                                                                                                                                                      
  <%= item.name %>                                                                                                                                                                        
<% end) %>
```

More details here:
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/templates.html